# Function keysym_to_keycode return 0

Tags: python-3.x, xlib

i use code below to get the keycode of 'a' and simulate keyboard input,but it return 0,
which lead error below:

```
X protocol error:
<Class 'Xlib.error.badValue'> : code = 2, resource id sequence_number = 20, major_opco de = 134, minor_opcode = 2
 X protocol error:
<Class 'Xlib.error.badValue'> : : code = 2, resource id = sequence_number = 22, major_opco de = 134, minor_opcode = 2
```

```
from Xlib import X, XK, display
from Xlib.ext import xtest

d = display.Display()
keycode = d.keysym_to_keycode(XK.string_to_keysym('a'))
print("keycode:", keycode)
xtest.fake_input(d, X.KeyPress, keycode)
d.sync()
xtest.fake_input(d, X.KeyRelease, keycode)
d.sync()
```

i try to install xlib again with command ：`pip3 install python_xlib-0.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl --user` 
but it doesn`t work. i can not get root access permissions ; so i use this command.